# OLEDB Debugging

Tags: .net, debugging, oledb

i'm using an ASP.NET 2.0 app (running in a Windows Server 2003 environment) connection to an informix db using IBM Client Provider.

The app work fine and pretty fast but I'm experiencing random oledb connection error like this :

> no error message available, result code: -2147417851(0x80010105).
>
> Stack Trace:    at
>   system.data.oledb.oledbconnectioninternal..ctor(oledbconnectionstring
>   constr, oledbconnection connection)   at
>   system.data.oledb.oledbconnectionfactory.createconnection(dbconnectionoptions
>   options, object poolgroupproviderinfo, dbconnectionpool pool,
>   dbconnection owningobject)   at
>   system.data.providerbase.dbconnectionfactory.createnonpooledconnection(dbconnection
>   owningconnection, dbconnectionpoolgroup poolgroup)   at
>   system.data.providerbase.dbconnectionfactory.getconnection(dbconnection
>   owningconnection)   at
>   system.data.providerbase.dbconnectionclosed.openconnection(dbconnection
>   outerconnection, dbconnectionfactory connectionfactory)   at
>   system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.open()   at
>   hltlib.oledbdatabase.initcommand() in
>   c:\hltdesktop\hltdesktop.legacy\oledbdatabase.cs:line 62

The only way to make this error disappear is to reset IIS.

Have anyone never had this problem ? Is there a windows oledb debugger and/or tracer that i can enable to troubleshoot this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it could be caused by the OLEDB connection pooling/its implementation in the Provider. Try to disable OLEDB services in the registry to prevent the connection pooling for the provider. See MS documentation on how to do this. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Since we do not know more about your system architecture and functionality of your application. The true cause of the problem is unknown

[According to this,](http://forums.asp.net/post/77316.aspx)
I think you have to  convert the whole code to use the ODBC.NET data provider. Since then, there were no more errors.